# Calling a win 32 C Library function from a VB 6.0 dll crashes

Tags: c, vb6

I have a C Library Cdll.dll which has the function

```
int _stdcall AddVersion(int repval) 
{
    return (repval + 10);
}
```

I am calling this AddVersion function from a VB dll.

```
Private Declare Function AddVersion Lib "cdll.dll" (ByVal Repval As Integer) As Integer
...

Public Function VbMessageHandler(ByRef intVal As Integer) As Integer
   intVal = AddVersion(10)
End Function
```

I am calling this VB dll from a C dll by creating a COM wrapper for the VB dll.

```
ret = ObjVbclass->VbMessageHandler(&IntegerValue);
```

when I use this VBWrapper dll in my C exe application, it crashes by throwing Runtime exception.

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration is wrong.  A VB6 Integer is 16-bits for historical reasons, a C int is 32-bits.  Use Long instead.

```
Private Declare Function AddVersion Lib "cdll.dll" (ByVal Repval As Long) As Long
```

Comment: Using Long also didn't avoid the crash. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You'll need to describe "crash".

Comment: The VBwrapperdll(C dll) is executed from a thread in a C application. The thread exits with an exception (observed while debugging the app). No output is received. Error handler is directly called in the VB application.